# Why physical address of Aarch64 kernel image is nonnegative?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, arm64

I'm recently learning about booting system of Linux kernel. (v4.6, with ARM64 arch.)

In the source code `arch/arm64/kernel/head.S`, definition of `__PHYS_OFFSET` is:

`#define __PHYS_OFFSET   (KERNEL_START - TEXT_OFFSET)`

where `KERNEL_START` is simply defined to be `_text` section.

And if I'm right, `TEXT_OFFSET` is a random number determined during kernel compile, as /arch/arm64/Makefile says:

`TEXT_OFFSET := $(shell awk 'BEGIN {srand(); printf "0x%03x000\n", int(512 * rand())}')`

so that the kernel image file has random location, as the linker script `/arch/arm64/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S` includes:

```
. = KIMAGE_VADDR + TEXT_OFFSET; 
.head.text : {                          
    _text = .;
    HEAD_TEXT
}
```

Here, `KIMAGE_VADDR` is a virtual address `0xFFFF000000000000 + 128M`. Since `TEXT_OFFSET` is added, section `_text` will be randomly located.

Rest parts of head.S map `KIMAGE_VADDR` to `__PHYS_OFFSET` to enable MMU.

My question is this: is `__PHYS_OFFSET = _text - TEXT_OFFSET` always nonnegative?

I don't know where would be exact physical location of `_text`, but I think `512 * rand()` might be as big as `512 * 32767 ~ 10MB`.

Do I make sense? Is there any reason makes these codes safe?

Answer (score 1):

`vmlinux.lds.S` does:

```
. = KIMAGE_VADDR + TEXT_OFFSET;
```

followed by

```
_text = .;
```

So `_text = KIMAGE_VADDR + TEXT_OFFSET`. When you then subtract `TEXT_OFFSET`, `__PHYS_OFFSET` will be the same as `KIMAGE_VADDR`.

Thus, if `KIMAGE_VADDR` is non-negative, so is `__PHYS_OFFSET`.

Comment: Well, I thought `KIMAGE_VADDR` must be virtual address(as its name says), since physical address 0xFFFF000000000000 + 128M is unrealistic. Is it really a physical address?